# How to automatically enable accessibility setting for android

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I am using [AccessibilityService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html) for my app. The problem is I need to enable it from Accessibility setting manually, is there a way to automatically do that so the user of my app don't need to do it manually ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fortunately no, for obvious privacy and security reasons. Malware authors would **love** it if they could start spying on user input automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is reasonable, but I do want to point out the accessibility shortcut. Android phones allow you to set up a hardware shortcut (like volume and power button at the same time on my device) that will allow them to easily toggle their default accessibility service choice.